# aggregate a large table by 2 columns in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, windows-7

I would like to aggregate a table by a column in SQL server.

Input: (may have 2  million rows, the number of value1 may be increased from 4 to 30, value2 are always 4 digit int. Name1 may have 2k+ distinct values.)

```
Name1 (varchar),  value1 (int),  value2 (int)
Racaw                      1                        1900 
Racaw                      2                        1100 
Racaw                      3                        1600 
Racaw                      4                        1200 
efvsef                     1                        1700 
efvsef                     2                        1200 
efvsef                     3                        1100 
efvsef                     4                        1000 
sdwyw                      1                        1900 
sdwyw                      2                        1100 
sdwyw                      3                        1600 
sdwyw                      4                        1200 
yubon                      1                        1700 
yubon                      2                        1200 
yubon                      3                        1100 
yubon                      4                        1000
```

Each name1 has only 4 "value1"s.

Output:

```
Name1 (varchar),  value1 (int),                 value2 (int), group_id
Racaw                    1                        1900             1
Racaw                    2                        1100             1
Racaw                    3                        1600             1
Racaw                    4                        1600             1
efvsef                   1                        1700             2
efvsef                   2                        1200             2
efvsef                   3                        1000             2
efvsef                   4                        1000             2
sdwyw                    1                        1900             1
sdwyw                    2                        1100             1
sdwyw                    3                        1600             1
sdwyw                    4                        1600             1
yubon                    1                        1700             2
yubon                    2                        1200             2
yubon                    3                        1000             2
yubon                    4                        1000             2
```

So, in the output, each Name1 is grouped by column value2.

In each "Name1", the numbers of "value2 " may be very large, e.g. 500  .

I want to try a checksum for value2 at each Name1 but I cannot find a built-in function in SQL server.

I tried to order the table by name1, value1, value2, but I am not sure how to assign group_id, which can be used to identify the duplicated combination value1 and value2 across name1.

**UPDATE**

BECAUSE

```
Name1 (varchar),  value1 (int),                 value2 (int), 
Racaw                    1                        1900             
Racaw                    2                        1100             
Racaw                    3                        1600             
Racaw                    4                        1600
```

are duplicated with

```
Name1 (varchar),  value1 (int),                 value2 (int), 
sdwyw                    1                        1900             
sdwyw                    2                        1100             
sdwyw                    3                        1600             
sdwyw                    4                        1600
```

except the Name1. They have same value1 and value2. **So, they are assigned the same group_id to mark out they are duplicated.**

Are there some built-in functions that can calculate a **checksum** based on the values of a column group by name1 ? In this way, the duplicated ones can be found easily.

Thanks,

Comment: How is adding a group number an aggregate? And do you have an order for the group numbers?

Comment: How to add a group number ?

Comment: group number should start from 1 and continuous.

Comment: I don't know because this question is not very clear to me. I see you have some sample data but you also have two sets of desired output.

Comment: I get starting by 1, but what is the logic for assigning those numbers? You need a way to order this table to assign group numbers.

Comment: The table can be ordered by name1, value1, value2, but how to assign group_id ?

Comment: Why do you say group number should be continuous, when your example shows groups 1, then 2, then 1 AGAIN, then 2 AGAIN?   "Continuous" to me means 1, 2, 3, 4...   What is the logic why `sdwyw` is group 1?   What is the logic why in your final output, group 1 is `Racaw` and not `sdwyw`?

Comment: You can use ROW_NUMBER() to assign unique group_id to each unique combination of Name1, Value1 and Value2.

Comment: I need to find unique combination of Value1 and Value2 group by name1. Please see the UPDATE.

Comment: With your recent update it seems you have some serious flaws in your data structure.

Comment: please point out the flaw, thx

Comment: You are looking for "duplicate groups" across rows. There is something very wrong with that. You have a relation now with sets of rows, I don't even know what normal form that violates because it really goes against the whole concept of relational data. Maybe you need each set of values in another table with a group number?

Comment: In UPDATE part, it is clear to show that "Racaw" and "sdwyw" have same value1 and value2. They are "duplicated" in this way. You can put the results into another table as long as the correct group_ids are assigned.

Comment: There is no way short of extremely ugly and lengthy code to do what you are asking. Your data does not allow this type of thing easily.

Comment: @user3448011 - Sean Lange is right, it is extremely lengthy code. One work around could be, after you get unique group_id by Name1, you can use CURSOR to compare all groups (two groups at a time) and assign minimum group_id to the matching groups. That way you will end up having group_id based on unique Value1 and Value2 pairs by Name1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT Name1, value1, value2, DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Name1) AS 'group_id'
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Name1, value1, value2 FROM TableName) A
```

Comment: I just changed the SQL after looking at the updated question, try now if it works.

Comment: the duplicated ones should be assigned same group_id, please check the UPDTAE. thx

Answer (score 0):

Your question is extremely unclear. You have two sets of "desired output" but they are conflicting with each other and the comments about group number being continuous. I think you probably want to use DENSE_RANK here but it is hard to say for sure.

Notice I posted sample data in a consumable format so other can easily start working on the problem and not have to spend time creating data. This is something you should do in the future.

```
DECLARE @Something TABLE
(
    name1 VARCHAR(20)
    , value1 INT
    , value2 INT
)

INSERT @Something
(
    name1,
    value1,
    value2
)
VALUES
('Racaw', 1, 1900),
('Racaw', 2, 1100), 
('Racaw', 3, 1600), 
('Racaw', 4, 1200), 
('efvsef', 1, 1700), 
('efvsef', 2, 1200), 
('efvsef', 3, 1100), 
('efvsef', 4, 1000), 
('sdwyw', 1, 1900), 
('sdwyw', 2, 1100), 
('sdwyw', 3, 1600), 
('sdwyw', 4, 1200), 
('yubon', 1, 1700), 
('yubon', 2, 1200), 
('yubon', 3, 1100), 
('yubon', 4, 1000) 

SELECT name1,
       value1,
       value2
       , DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY name1)
       , RANK() OVER(ORDER BY name1)
FROM @Something
```

Comment: I have tried your solution , it does not work, the duplicated rows are assigned different group_id. Thx, In the example, there should be only 2 distinct group_ids. The "UPDATE" part has show this.

Comment: I have updated the OP so that only one output is preferred, thx

Comment: There are exactly ZERO duplicate rows in your sample data. Perhaps you need to explain your desired output more clearly.

Comment: please check the UPDATE.  "name1" should not be counted to check duplicate ! thx

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to concatenate the Value1 and Value2 columns into a string for each Name1.  You can then use `Dense_Rank` as mentioned in other answers.

Assuming the table created in [@Sean Lange's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44680154/1043031), you can concatenate the Value1 and Value2 columns using:

```
SELECT DISTINCT S2.Name1,
(
  SELECT  CAST(S1.Value1 AS VARCHAR)+','+ CAST(value2 AS VARCHAR)+','
  FROM    @Something S1
  WHERE  S1.Name1 = S2.Name1
  ORDER BY S1.Name1, S1.Value1, S1.Value2
  FOR XML PATH('')
) v
FROM @Something S2
```

This will give:

```
Name1   v
efvsef  1,1700,2,1200,3,1100,4,1000,
Racaw   1,1900,2,1100,3,1600,4,1200,
sdwyw   1,1900,2,1100,3,1600,4,1200,
yubon   1,1700,2,1200,3,1100,4,1000,
```

You can then use Dense_Rank() to calculate the GroupID values:

```
SELECT *
FROM @Something s
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT x.Name1
        , DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY x.v) GroupID
    FROM
    (
       SELECT DISTINCT S2.Name1,
       (
          SELECT  CAST(S1.Value1 AS VARCHAR)+','+CAST(value2 AS VARCHAR)+','
          FROM    @Something S1
          WHERE  S1.Name1 = S2.Name1
          ORDER BY S1.Name1, S1.Value1, S1.Value2
          FOR XML PATH('')
       ) v
       FROM @Something S2
    ) x
) r ON s.Name1 = r.Name1
ORDER BY s.Name1
```